# Text Layout class doesn't work with printer

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm using Delphi 11, Firemonkey. I tried to do some printing (text, shapes, bitmaps) using only `TPrinter.Canvas` methods. Everything worked fine.

But there is also this thing called `TTextLayout`, which is very useful for formatting text. However, when I tried printing using this class, I couldn't see any text. On the other hand, drawing onto regular canvases, like `TPaintBox.Canvas` or `TBitmap.Canvas` using `TTextLayout` works fine.

---

This is my code (`TButton` (×3), `TPaintBox`, `TPrintDialog`, `TSaveDialog`):

```
uses
  FMX.TextLayout;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PaintBox1.Repaint;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoPrint;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DrawToFile;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas);
begin
  DrawSomething(Canvas);
end;

procedure TForm1.DoPrint;
begin
  if PrintDialog1.Execute then begin
    Printer.ActivePrinter.SelectDPI(1200, 1200);
    Printer.Orientation := TPrinterOrientation.poLandscape;
    Printer.BeginDoc;
    try
      if Printer.Canvas.BeginScene() then try
        DrawSomething(Printer.Canvas);
      finally
        Printer.Canvas.EndScene;
      end;
    finally
      Printer.EndDoc;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.DrawToFile;
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  if SaveDialog1.Execute then begin
    Bmp := TBitmap.Create(300, 300);
    try
      Bmp.Clear(TAlphaColors.White);
      if Bmp.Canvas.BeginScene() then try
        DrawSomething(Bmp.Canvas);
      finally
        Bmp.Canvas.EndScene;
      end;
      Bmp.SaveToFile(SaveDialog1.FileName);
    finally
      Bmp.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.DrawSomething(Canvas: TCanvas);
var
  tl: TTextLayout;
  BoldFont: TFont;
  StrokeBrush: TStrokeBrush;
begin
  tl := nil;
  BoldFont := nil;
  StrokeBrush := nil;
  try
    tl := TTextLayoutManager.DefaultTextLayout.Create();
    BoldFont := TFont.Create;
    StrokeBrush := TStrokeBrush.Create(TBrushKind.Solid, TAlphaColors.Blue);

    BoldFont.SetSettings('Arial', 96, TFontStyleExt.Create([TFontStyle.fsBold]));

    StrokeBrush.Thickness := 10.0;

    tl.BeginUpdate;
    try
      tl.TopLeft := TPointF.Create(0,0);
      tl.MaxSize := TPointF.Create(300, 300);
      tl.Text := 'Lorem'#$0A'ipsum';
      tl.WordWrap := True;
      tl.HorizontalAlign := TTextAlign.Leading;
      tl.VerticalAlign := TTextAlign.Leading;
      tl.Color := TAlphaColors.Black;
      tl.Font.SetSettings('Arial', 96, TFontStyleExt.Create([]));
      tl.Opacity := 1.0;
      tl.AddAttribute(TTextRange.Create(3, 5), TTextAttribute.Create(BoldFont, TAlphaColors.Black));
    finally
      tl.EndUpdate;
    end;
    tl.RenderLayout(Canvas);
    Canvas.DrawLine(TPointF.Create(10, 20), TPointF.Create(110, 120), 1.0, StrokeBrush);
  finally
    StrokeBrush.Free;
    BoldFont.Free;
    tl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

`Button1` repaints `TPaintBox`, `Button2` prints, `Button3` creates an image file. Here are my results:

Application:
[Application screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHc4D.png)

Microsoft Print to PDF (got the same result from an actual printer):
[PDF screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urblG.png)

Image file:
[Image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPAll.png)

As you can see, both `TControl.Canvas` and `TBitmap.Canvas` have no problem with rendering the text layout. Only the printer's canvas doesn't show the text. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because `TTextLayout.RenderLayout(Canvas)` calls `TTextLayoutD2D.DoDrawLayout` which expects a `TCanvasD2D` canvas, which presumably the printer canvas is not:

```
  if (ACanvas = nil) or not (ACanvas is TCanvasD2D) or Text.IsEmpty or (FLayout = nil) then
    Exit;
```

This might warrant a bug report with Embarcadero, but in the meantime, one way around this is to draw the text to a `TBitMap` (as you already do with `Button3`), and draw that bitmap to the printer canvas:

```
procedure TForm1.DoPrint;
var Bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  if PrintDialog1.Execute then begin
    Bmp:=TBitmap.Create(300,300);
    try
      Bmp.Clear(TAlphaColors.White);
      if Bmp.Canvas.BeginScene() then try
    DrawSomething(Bmp.Canvas);
      finally
    Bmp.Canvas.EndScene;
      end;
    finally
      Printer.ActivePrinter.SelectDPI(1200, 1200);
      Printer.Orientation := TPrinterOrientation.poLandscape;
      Printer.BeginDoc;
      try
        if Printer.Canvas.BeginScene() then try
          Printer.Canvas.DrawBitmap(Bmp,Bmp.Bounds,Bmp.Bounds,1)
        finally
          Printer.Canvas.EndScene;
        end;
      finally
        Printer.EndDoc;
      end;
      Bmp.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

NB: Not being a regular user of `try...finally`, I don't know if I have the best arrangement of those.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Philip J. Rayment's answer, I managed to find another solution.

The problem is with `TTextLayout` creation: `DefaultTextLayout` returns the default text layout class for the running platform ([documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/FMX.TextLayout.TTextLayoutManager.DefaultTextLayout)). This is usually different to what printer requires. In these situations, we need to use `TTextLayoutManager.TextLayoutByCanvas()` method.

```
// ...
begin
  tl := nil;
  BoldFont := nil;
  StrokeBrush := nil;
  try
    // tl := TTextLayoutManager.DefaultTextLayout.Create(); -- wrong
    tl := TTextLayoutManager.TextLayoutByCanvas(Canvas.ClassType).Create(); // correct
    BoldFont := TFont.Create;
    StrokeBrush := TStrokeBrush.Create(TBrushKind.Solid, TAlphaColors.Blue);

    BoldFont.SetSettings('Arial', 96, TFontStyleExt.Create([TFontStyle.fsBold]));
// ...
```

However, Text Layouts for different types of Canvases behave differently. For example, GDI+ doesn't support text attributes (different text formats within one text):

| Philip's solution with bitmap | My solution without bitmap |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

The layouts also have different padding, so, with enabled word wrap and too small `MaxSize`, you can get quite unexpected results (removed formatting this time):

| Philip's solution with bitmap | My solution without bitmap |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Used same settings, but different `TTextLayout` classes.

This is kind of awkward, because one would expect the descendants to act as mere "wrappers" and produce the same results.

So, I think **Philip's solution does a better job** than this one. Although, `DefaultTextLayout` still might return different Text Layouts on different platforms. Maybe one day, Embarcadero will fix the `TTextLayout`'s behavior.